# CursorAdapter and FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER

Tags: android, android-cursoradapter, android-loadermanager, android-cursorloader

In my ListView Activity, using LoaderManager to manager cursor and also have a Custom CursorAdapter

```
mAdapter = new CustomCursorAdapter(getActivity(), null,CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);
setListAdapter(mAdapter);
```

While registering the Adapter, a null cursor is passed which is managed by LoaderManager

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(3, null, this);
```

Now need to implement SectionIndexer for this CustomCursorAdapter. My problem is that in the CustomCursorAdapter constructor the cursor initially will be null, how do I know when I have the Cursor ready.

There is a

```
getCursor();
```

method that is available to get the cursor in CursorAdapter, but in which call back method I know for sure that LoaderManager has finished loading the Cursor with data is ready to be manipulated

thanks

Answer (score 2):

> In which callback method do I know for sure that `LoaderManager` has finished loading the `Cursor` with data that is ready to be manipulated?

The `LoaderManager` doesn't "load" anything... rather, it *instructs* the `Loader` to query the data source (a `ContentProvider` in this case, I assume). The `CursorLoader` then notifies the `LoaderManager` when its load is complete and the `Cursor` has been created. Finally, the `LoaderManager` calls the callback's `onLoadFinished()` method (which you have most likely implemented in your `Activity`) with the loaded data.

Also, you don't need to use `CursorAdapter.FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER` with the `LoaderManager`... the `Loader` registers a `ContentObserver` on its own, so registering one for the `CursorAdapter` is both useless and a waste.

Answer (score -1):

there is a **onContentChanged()** method that triggers when there is some change in the cursor. This works if you are working with content providers and URI's. Hope this help.